# $\{\,z\in \mathbb C : \operatorname{Im}(z)>-1 , |z|<2\, \}$ onto upper half space $\{\,z\in \mathbb C : \operatorname{Im}(z)>0 \,\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I am search an one to one mapping that maps the domain $$\{\,z\in \mathbb C :  \operatorname{Im}(z)>-1 , |z|<2\, \}$$ onto upper half space $$\{\,z\in \mathbb C :  \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\, \}$$ comformally.

I am confused, can some one help me.

Comment: What is your confusion ???

Comment: I have examined many known mapps but I have failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given shape has two vertices at $\pm\sqrt 3-i$ where the boundary lines intersect at $120^\circ$ angles.

Get rid of one of the vertices via a Möbius transform that takes it to $\infty$. By the properties of Möbius transforms, the circle and line boundary become lines, and they still intersect at $120^\circ$ in the (relocated) remaining vertex. Translate this to the origin and raise to the $\frac32$ power to straighten out the angle to $180^\circ$. Maybe you need to do a rotation in the end, check that.